# Perl Map from one array to another  (update simplified it)

Tags: perl, dictionary

Thank you for reading.

Goal:

1. I want to be Shifting  emails addresses, aa@gmail.com, bb@yahoo.com from one array to another.
2. In a number of 200 every time I want to make use of that list.
3. These emails MUST be from different domain names. BUT the list is already sorted by domain names, (it was done with MAP)
4. So to put it more simple: it is about informing the pointer that loops through the array where it has to fetch the email, and it will be every time it finds a different domain name, up to a maximum of 200 emails.

So, I have come up with (apologies for this) broken pseudocode, because it is today the first time I am reading about MAP and it turns out this block is a bit complicated.

Howto:

```
  @destination_list =

map {$_->[0]}  # map back

for(my $i = 1; $i<201; ++$i) # this is to do the round of 200 emails per day
if($_ != $1 ) # compares 2 domains 

{


shift(@oldlist); # extract one from the old list and send it to the new list



}


map { m/@([a-zA-Z0-9\-.]*)\b/; [$_, $1]} # this gets what the domain name is
  @oldlist
```

thank you

Comment: This is all very chaotic. What are you trying to do? I believe you have some sort of list that lives outside your program. You read that, and you want to process only some of its elements. Is that correct? Why don't you show a small part of that list (like 2 or 3 elements) and tell us how you save and load it. That might help.

Comment: The starting list is nothing but emails, one per line. So, I have described in detail what I want to do. Extract 200 emails from that list and pass them to the destination list. These emails must be from different domain names, but the list is already sorted by domain names. Once an email has been extracted it should not be available for the next time I want to use it, else, it could be picked up again.

Comment: Do you mean email addresses or actual emails with a header and some text? Do you store that in a file and read it every time your program runs?

Comment: Yes, it is just a csv file, pepe@gmail.com, maria@gmail.com just that. So I extract 200 from this list, but must be from different domains, otherwise a company could be getting 5 emails (one for each worker) at one time.

Comment: Try not to be so obsessed with `map`. It is useful, but not always the way to go. Sometimes a more verbose `foreach` loop is the better choice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13275/discussion-between-simbabque-and-iaintunderstand)

Comment: keep changing email? are you spammer?

Comment: If you are sending the same message to multiple recipients in the same domain, most sites would prefer that you deliver to them all at once, not the other way around. A common practice is to put a placeholder address in the `To:` header and basically `Bcc:` the actual recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we came up with in the chat. It processes the whole list each time and yields an array-ref full of lists, one for each day. It's possible to supply the day one wants, as well as a 'do not use this domain again after day x' blacklist.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

my $only_index = 3; # Read from command line with $ARGV[0] or use Getopt::Long

my %blacklist = (       # Each key in this hash represents one index/day
  '2' => [ 'a', 'b' ],  # and has an arrayref of domains that have replied on
  '3' => [ 'c' ],       # that day. We look at all keys smaller than the current
);                      # index in each iteration and ignore all these domains 

my @domains; # holds the domains we have already seen for each list
my @lists = ([]); # Holds all the lists
my %moved; # the addresses we moved to the back
my $i = 0;
my @addresses = <DATA>;

while (@addresses) {
  my $address = shift @addresses;
  chomp $address;
  $address =~ m/@([a-zA-Z0-9\-.]*)\b/;
  my $domain = $1;

  # If the domain has answered, do not do it again (finally, your map ;-))
  next if 
    grep { /$domain/ } 
    map { exists $blacklist{$_} ? @{ $blacklist{$_} } : () }  (0..$i);
  next if exists $moved{$address}; # THIS line was  missing
  $i++ if (@{ $lists[$i] } == 2 
           || (exists $moved{$address} && @addresses < 1));
  if (exists $domains[$i]->{$domain}) {
    push @addresses, $address;
    $moved{$address}++;
#     say "pushing $address to moved"; # debug
  } else {
    $domains[$i]->{$domain}++;
    # send the email
#     say "added $address to $i";      # debug
    push @{ $lists[$i] }, $address;
  }
}
# print Dumper \@lists;           # Show all lists
print Dumper $lists[$only_index]; # Only show the selected list
1;


__DATA__
1@a
2@a
3@a
1@b
2@b
1@c
2@c
3@c
1@d
2@d
3@d
4@d
1@e
1@f
1@g
1@h
4@a
5@a
4@c
```

Comment: That was fabulous. I have no words as I am so thankful. For the dedicated time, and for the help it provided me with. And for the teaching. It has been a Lotto. It would take me 50 years to attain that level of expertise. Of course, I am still learning from the code because it is far beyond my level, but reading books and comparing syntax I am beginning to unravel this. Vielen Dank nochmals!

Comment: Hello simbabque. Hmm, today I have tested the application with just 20 emails. It never finishes working. It manages up to 8 quite quick but after that, it never finishes computing and does not show any results in the console. Could it be that the algorithm makes it go exponentially to an extent that it is impossible to finish it? it does not hang, it simply blows the ventilator of the cpu but with a blank console

Comment: There was a problem with an infinite loop that occurred when there were more email addresses per iteration than there were email addresses that were being moved. It did not stop moving the leftover ones. I added a fix for that. See updated code above.

Answer (score 3):

Minimises the number of groups by always picking from the domains with the most email addresses first.

```
my %addrs_by_domain;
for my $addr (@addrs) {
   my $domain = ... extract domain of $addr ...;
   push @{ $addrs_by_domain{$domain} }, $addr;
}

while (%addrs_by_domain) {
   my @domains_by_freq =
      sort { @{ $addrs_by_domain{$b} } <=> @{ $addrs_by_domain{$a} }
       keys(%addrs_by_domain);

   splice @domains_by_freq, 200;

   my @group;
   for my $domain (@domains_by_freq) {
      push @group, shift( @{ $addrs_by_domain{$domain} } );
      delete( $addrs_by_domain{$domain} )
         if !@{ $addrs_by_domain{$domain} };
   }

   do_it(@group);
}
```

Comment: (The `splice` will issue a spurious warning in older versions of Perl. Turning off warnings for that line or adding a simple conditional will make it backwards compatible.)